# Background Subtraction for Road Traffic Monitoring

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, background-subtraction

I have to detect cars on a video stream (recorded) and provide some traffic data.  I have read that background subtraction is the most important step so that we can be able to extract foreground objects.

The question is, how do we do this for colour frames? Articles I have read talk more of black and white images.

I would like to use automatic background removal, which uses frame differencing (in my understanding).

If I did the removal in gray scale, would I still be able to replay the video with the tracked object in colour? Because the point is being able to show the tracked car on the original video.

Comment: In what language or on what platform?

Comment: @Maurits: This is a language independent question

Comment: @Maurits: I'll be using OpenCV and Visual-C++ if this helps you guide me... But I didn't see it necessary to tag as it is not about coding yet...

Comment: @monksy I respectfully disagree. The question asked is quite basic and counting cars in traffic is one of the common computer vision demos. Pending the platform I can link to tutorials in C++/Python or Matlab

Comment: @Maurits it is a basic computer vision question, the tool kit and language used to complete the task is irrelevant

Comment: @Maurits You may link the tutorials... Sure they'll help a lot... C++ would do, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gray is used because it reduces the information needed, without taking out the overall meaning from the information.

Background extraction is the extraction of the "general appearance of the scene." The foreground is all of the objects added to the image. Taking the difference of images technically will work. However, averaging all of the images will give you the best version of the background.  [This assumes some things but I'll go into that later]. Once you have the background, that will help you create a mask that you can use to apply it to a simple image. Once you use the mask that'll separate out the foreground objects and use those to what you wish.

The color is really only useful to you for tracking. [Mean color shift will probably help you in tracking].

Assumptions: This is assuming that you'll have enough video to create an average scene, and that the foreground object will eventually disappear. [Otherwise they'll turn into the background: aka a broken down vehicle being left]. Also the way you average is another issue, significant season changes can modify the background. [After winter roads tend to crack]

Comment: Ok, to bring a bit of implementation here(don't know if it's allowed). I have used the opencv class BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 to do the background subtraction although can't do shadow elimination yet. It's doing it very nicely. I think this has eliminated my background elimination problem. :)